# Reading pdf in rails error "Input must be an IO-like object or a filename error on"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf-reader

I'm trying to read a pdf file in rails using [pdf-reader](https://rubygems.org/gems/pdf-reader) gem of rails.
Here is my code

```
<%
reader = PDF::Reader.new('/uploads/pdf/pdf_1.pdf')
puts reader.pdf_version
puts reader.info
puts reader.metadata
puts reader.page_count
%>
```

There problem is in loading the PDF file.
Also I can access my PDF using this url `http://localhost:3000/uploads/pdf/pdf_1.pdf`

This is the error I'm getting:

```
input must be an IO-like object or a filename
```

IDK what I'm doing wrong.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like it tries to get file `/uploads/pdf/pdf_1.pdf` from root of your system, not from root of your web-app.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use:

```
reader = PDF::Reader.new(Rails.root.join('uploads/pdf/pdf_1.pdf'))
```

And if you want to display it on page you should do something like:

```
<% reader = PDF::Reader.new(Rails.root.join('uploads/pdf/pdf_1.pdf')) %>
<%= reader.pdf_version + reader.info + reader.metadata + reader.page_count %>
```

Comment: Still same error.Btw I tried using the full path "/home/workspace..." and there was no error but it weren't outputting anything.

Comment: So you should use full path, don't know why `Rails.root...` doesn't help to get it. And where do you expect to see output? On console? You could try to create simple script to play with this file...

Comment: Actually I'm trying to view its data on a view file.I need to find how to make it load relatively, btw thanks for your help.

Comment: Updated a bit to proper erb